# innerHTML jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class of red to any TD cell that has the text of [RW] but am doing something wrong. Firebug gives an error of typeFunction.

```
$("td").innerHtml("RW").addClass("red")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery, `.innerHTML()` isn't a method. You should instead use filters:

```
$("td:contains('RW')").addClass("red");
```

Comment: What if it should be for each TD that has RW inside?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'RW') {
    $(this).addClass('red')
  }
})
```

Comment: I would use `filter` not `each`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').filter(function(index){return $(this).html() == 'RW';}).addClass('red');
```

Answer (score -1):

a) Use html(), not innerHtml(). innerHtml() is not a JQuery method.
b) The innerHtml function with no arguments will return the current content of the element. With a string argument it will set the content. So even with

```
$('td').html('RW').addClass('red')
```

you're going to change the content of every td element to 'RW' and then add the red class to all of them.

You'll need to refine your selector or use a conditional.